# Spring MVC request mapping challenge

Tags: spring-mvc

I have a Spring MVC application I'm working on and have come to a stopping point.  When I link from index.jsp to what I believe is a controller request mapping I get a 404 -- The requested resource () is not available.

The console output when I build shows this:

Mar 16, 2011 1:07:24 PM org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.AbstractUrlHandlerMapping registerHandler
INFO: Mapped URL path [/ExpenseRpt/Project.*] onto handler 'projectAddEditController'

The URL looks like this:

> http://localhost:8081/ExpenseRpt/Project.html

The request mapping in the controller looks like this:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ExpenseRpt/Project")
```

CLEARLY, I'm missing something important.  All of my mappings are failing the same way.

Answer (score 0):

Try to map your controller with

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/ExpenseRpt/Project.html")
```